# How to get log server accessing to Microsoft CRM Webservices 3.0

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm tring to call Microsoft CRM Webservices 3.0 with a Php Soap Client (Zend_Soap) and I got this exception :

> Server was unable to process request (0xc00ce556).

So, I Want to access log files. Anyone known where I could find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try see this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490/en-us) that works also with CRM 3.0, you have activate the trace to have access to logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Link. I found three important paramaters into regedit file : TraceEnabled(1),TraceDirectory(Log file directory),TraceRefresh(99). But it doesn't work. Should I reboot my computer?

Comment: Try CRMDiagTool check this [link](http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/microsoft-dynamics-crm-3-0-4-0-support-tools/) that had links for that.